# Playing Chunked Videos from AWS as a Single Video in React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, video

I am working on a project where I am uploading large videos to AWS in chunks due to their size. After uploading, I receive chunked video URLs which I save to my mongoose database using Node.js on my server. Here's an example of the stored URLs:

```
const chunkedTutorialVideo = [
    'https://myBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/chunk_0_174784378.mp4',
    'https://myBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/chunk_1_3727287197.mp4',
    'https://myBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/chunk_2_829984678.mp4',
];
```

In my React app, I've implemented a basic video player. Now, I'm facing the challenge of playing these chunked videos as a single video, similar to how it was initially. When a user visits the ViewTutorialPage, I want the video to load, and upon clicking the play button, it should seamlessly play the chunked video URLs as a single video.

I've been researching extensively to find a solution for this, but so far, I haven't been able to make it work. I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to achieve this functionality in my React app.

Thank you in advance for your help!